# Why is the picture I added in an Gmail email draft disappearing upon loading the draft?

Tags: gmail

This 15-second video show the issue: http://youtu.be/a6kimyqrYpU . The picture I added in an Gmail email draft disappearing upon loading the draft. Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: You can try by inserting the picture as inline image.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you convert your files to jpg.

I have the same experience but only with some pictures. I believe the pictures that disappear are .png (snapshots). Jpgs do not seem to disappear.The pngs disappear from my drafts and also from my signature in the settings, but I have had no trouble with jpgs in either place.